# vlookup vba stops when find the first value from multiple worksheet how to make it continue works and find the next value in same cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have vba code for lookup in the entire sheet for the employee number and return back his total working days,

but the employee number can work in 2 places with different total days in different sheets

so the vlookup when it find the the employee number it return back the first total days from sheet and stop it doesn't continue to find the other total days

below is the VBA code

```vb
Function VLOOKUPWORKBOOK( _
         lookup_value As Variant, _
         table_array As Range, _
         col_index_num As Integer, _
         Optional range_lookup As Boolean, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_1 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_2 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_3 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_4 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_5 As String _
         )

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim value_to_return As Variant
Dim sheets_to_exclude As Variant
Dim CellsEmpty As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next

    sheets_to_exclude = Array(sheets_to_exclude_1, sheets_to_exclude_2, sheets_to_exclude_3, sheets_to_exclude_4, sheets_to_exclude_5)

    For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Not (UBound(Filter(sheets_to_exclude, mySheet.Name)) > -1) Then

            With mySheet

                Set table_array = .Range(table_array.Address)

                value_to_return = Application.VLookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)

            End With

            If Not IsEmpty(value_to_return) Then
                Exit For
            End If

        End If

    Next mySheet

    VLOOKUPWORKBOOK = value_to_return

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit For is why you're only getting one result. Your loop quits after finding one value. Remove Exit For and change value_to_return into an array that can return multiple values.

```vb
Function VLOOKUPWORKBOOK( _
         lookup_value As Variant, _
         table_array As Range, _
         col_index_num As Integer, _
         Optional range_lookup As Boolean, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_1 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_2 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_3 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_4 As String, _
         Optional sheets_to_exclude_5 As String _
         )

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim value_to_return() As Variant
    Dim ValCount As Long
    Dim sheets_to_exclude As Variant
    Dim CellsEmpty As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next
    
    sheets_to_exclude = Array(sheets_to_exclude_1, sheets_to_exclude_2, sheets_to_exclude_3, sheets_to_exclude_4, sheets_to_exclude_5)

    For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Not (UBound(Filter(sheets_to_exclude, mySheet.Name)) > -1) Then

            With mySheet

                Set table_array = .Range(table_array.Address)
                
                ReDim Preserve value_to_return(ValCount)
                value_to_return(ValCount) = Application.VLookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)
                ValCount = ValCount + 1
            
            End With

        End If

    Next mySheet

    VLOOKUPWORKBOOK = value_to_return

End Function
```